# VBA Offset acting strange?

Tags: vba, excel, offset

Maybe there's something I don't know, but I'm using Offset to find values in one cell and export them to another cell. There have been a few times, where Offset is not what I would expect. For instance, in the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendToMRP()
Dim AllSales As Worksheet
Dim SendToMRP As Worksheet
Dim ALS  As Range, STM  As Range, AL As Range, Rng As Range

Set AllSales = Worksheets("AllSales")
Set SendToMRP = Worksheets("SendToMRP")

With AllSales
    For Each ALS In Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3))
        If (ALS.Offset(0, 50) = "Yes") Then
        Else
            'ALS.Offset(0, 50) = "Yes"
            With SendToMRP.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3)
                .Offset(1, 0) = ALS.Offset(0, 0) ' OrderId
                .Offset(1, 1) = ALS.Offset(0, 1) ' StoreFront or    "Amazon"
                .Offset(1, 2) = ALS.Offset(0, 2) ' OrderType'
                .Offset(1, 3) = ALS.Offset(0, 3) ' PurchaseDate'
                .Offset(1, 4) = ALS.Offset(0, 15) ' This should be 4, but 15 is the correct setting
                .Offset(1, 5) = ALS.Offset(0, 5) ' and it continues back at 5

            End With
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

The second argument for Offset sometimes isn't what I would expect it to be and I'm not sure why this is. Hopefully someone can shed some insight into this? Thanks

Comment: Have no way yet to test your code but I think nesting `With` at different worksheet object will cause trouble, if you can check that first and see the outcome?

Comment: Or fully qualify your range here: `For Each ALS In Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3))`. It should contain a `.Range`.

Comment: @L42 that. Unqualified `Range` and `Rows` calls are implicitly refering to `Activesheet`. Now, the nested `With` blocks aren't helping readability either. But `Sheet1.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(3)` is almost certain to not work as intended.

Comment: If you have any merged cells neighboring the starting point then that can cause problems

Comment: I have `For Each ALS In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3)) `. But it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very helpful person at Excelforum.com helped me and provided this as the answer. It works, but I can't say that I fully understand why. I've used this code before without the dots and it too works, but this time it didn't. If someone could offer some guidance, it would be much appreciated.

```
With AllSales
For Each ALS In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(3))
    If (ALS.Offset(0, 50) = "Yes") Then
    Else
        'ALS.Offset(0, 50) = "Yes"
        With SendToMRP.Cells(SendToMRP.Rows.Count, 1).End(3)
            .Offset(1, 0) = ALS.Offset(0, 0) ' OrderId
            .Offset(1, 1) = ALS.Offset(0, 1) ' StoreFront or    "Amazon"
            .Offset(1, 2) = ALS.Offset(0, 2) ' OrderType'
            .Offset(1, 3) = ALS.Offset(0, 3) ' PurchaseDate'
            .Offset(1, 4) = ALS.Offset(0, 15) ' This should be 4, but 15 is the correct setting
            .Offset(1, 5) = ALS.Offset(0, 5) ' and it continues back at 5
        End With
    End If
Next
End With
```